# How to use slim for mailer text template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, slim-lang

I am using slim as the template engine for my rails app and would like to use slim for mailer templates as well.

There is no problem with html mailer templates (views/mailer/default_email.en.html.slim) but, I am not sure how to make the text templates work.

I have placed a text template in views/mailer/default_email.en.text.slim with this content:

```
Hello,

Your video is ready.
= @url

Thank you,
The A-Team
```

But the result is parsed as slim HTML, and looks like this:

```
<Hello>,</Hello><Your>video is ready.</Your><Click>the link below to watch it:</Click>http://watch.thy/video<Thank>you,</Thank><The>A-Team</The>
```

Other than prefixing every line with a pipe, isnt there a more natural way?
I even [looked for an embedded plugin](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/slim/frames#Embedded_engines__Markdown______) (like the markdown one) to say "plain text" but there is none.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Slim was designed to generate HTML, not plain text, so you'll have to either use the pipe prefix for each line or go with `.text.erb` templates. I'd use the ERB templates, especially if you don't have a lot of interpolation going on.

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping I missed something and what I want to do exists. Maybe a good feature request for slim, or a plugin like the markdown one.

Answer (score 5):

For what it's worth, you *can* actually go the Slim route without having to prefix each line with a pipe, like so:

```
|
  Hello,
  <br><br>
  Your video is ready.<br>
  #{@url}
  <br><br>
  Thank you,<br>
  The A-Team
```

I would definitely agree with **eugen** though, that the `text.erb` route is the best fit. Just providing another solution, in case somebody absolutely insisted on doing this in Slim. :-)

Comment: Actually, this is not a bad idea... I may try that. After using slim for a few days, looking at ERB hurts my eyes... Its like looking at javascript after you got used to coffeescript...

Comment: Haha, I hear ya. When I first started using Slim (not by choice), I hated it. But now I absolutely love it. Whenever I have to jump back to Erb and raw HTML, it feels so awkward and bloated.